# Setting a value only if a record exists (performing an update)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase's `setValue()` method sets a value in the db, even if a record does not exists (as expected).

**My question:** Is there a way to only set a value if a record exists? (perform an update)

I want to do an "*update if exists*" operation. I want to avoid doing 2 operations - checking if exists, and if so setting the value.

Comment: You can add a listener to the node where you want to write data to. And then check if the data exists using the `DataSnapshot.exists()` method.

Comment: So does that mean that every time I want to validate that a node exists before updating it, I need to add a listener for its value (query #1), check if it exists and then perform another query (query #2) to update its contents? Is there no other way using Firebase that says something like "update if exists"?

Comment: I don't think so. Although firebase is a great platform for creating your app, it's a shame that the firebase database still lacks some features like "update if exists". I really hope Google changes this someday.